# Safe operations on PortAudio's PaStreamFinishedCallback

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I'd like to know what operations are safe in PortAudio's `PaStreamFinishedCallback`. I know typically it is not a good idea to attempt operations that could block on the `PaStreamCallback` for playback as that could cause pops/glitches on the user's or other application's audio streams. Do the same limitations apply to the `PaStreamFinishedCallback`? I guess ultimately I'm curious if that callback is also called on the OS's audio thread.

Alternately, is there a function like `Pa_StopStream` that will block until the callback has returned `paComplete`/`paAbort`, but without inducing a stop? That'd actually be ideal for my use, since I have a thread that's the right place for me to clean up. I know I could achieve this by having my callback signal to my thread that it's done, and then the thread could call `Pa_StopStream` but that feels heavy handed.

edit: To give a bit more context about my use, I have a ring buffer that holds some PCM and uses a pthread condvar to signal when space is available in the buffer. One thread writes into this ring and then the `PaStreamCallback` reads out of the the other end. When things are finished, the writer sets a closed flag on the ring and then the callback drains whatever is left. I'd like to make sure my ring drains and that PortAudio flushes. The callback is the only place that knows when the ring drains, so returning `paComplete` feels appropriate. But then I need some way to know that it's ok to deallocate my ring.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that it depends highly on the host and the behavior may change over time even for one host. I went ahead and read the implementation, and I discovered a couple of useful pieces of information here.

`Pa_StopStream` will just invoke the host system's `Stop()`-like behavior. I didn't read all the implementations but presumably most have some sort of blocking `Stop()`. That means that it's unlikely that blocking for a stop, without actually asking for one, will be a supported behavior.

`PaStreamFinishedCallback` is also just a thin wrapper on the host's own stream stopped callback. For example, in OSX Core Audio this is a `Listener` on `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_IsRunning`. It's entirely up to the host how and when this is called. I think the smart play here is to be as cautious as possible -- assume no blocking operations are safe inside this callback.

So, if you're in the same situation as me where one thread feeds PCM into a ring buffer, and the `PaStreamCallback` reads from that ring, then you'll probably want to

- Subscribe to `PaStreamFinishedCallback`
- Producer thread closes ring buffer and lets `PaStreamCallback` drain it
- Return `paComplete` from `PaStreamCallback` when the ring is drained
- Signal the producer thread that work is done from `PaStreamFinishedCallback`, in my case using `pthread_cond_signal`
- Producer thread wakes up and cleans up by deallocating

Even signaling (and locking mutexes) from the audio thread is probably best to avoid, but it's hard to imagine there's an alternative. For regular reading from PCM ring buffer, the `PaStreamCallback` should probably spin some limited number of times before giving up. For the completion signal, the producer thread should lock and then immediately wait, so that it holds the lock as little as possible.